# Extend jQuery Plugin with additional function / override function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, extend, unslider

I need to extend a jQuery Plugin (https://github.com/idiot/unslider) in order to add additional behavior with another public method.

```
(function(){
    // Store a reference to the original remove method.
    var originalMethod = $.fn.unslider;
    // Define overriding method.
    $.fn.unslider = function(){

        // Execute the original method.
        originalMethod.apply( this, arguments );

        console.log( "Override method" );

        function test() {
            console.log("test called");
        }

        this.each(function() {
            // Operations for each DOM element
            console.log("each dom element?");

        }).data('unslider', {
            // Make test accessible from data instance
            test: test
        });

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I already managed to make the public method accessible when calling

```
var slider = $('#slider');
slider.data('unslider').test();
```

However, I want to keep the old behavior of unslider anyways, but extend the Plugin with another function. Does anyone have an idea?

I created a fiddle, so you can check whats happening:
My new function gets called, but the old ones are gone:
http://jsfiddle.net/b2os4s7e/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source of unslider, you can see it stores the Unslider instance inside the data:

```
    //  Enable multiple-slider support
    return this.each(function(index) {
        //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it
        var me = $(this),
            key = 'unslider' + (len > 1 ? '-' + ++index : ''),
            instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);

        //  Invoke an Unslider instance
        me.data(key, instance).data('key', key);
    });
```

In your code you're overwriting this object with your own object. However, the slider expects there to be an Unslider instance. So what you want to do is get this instance and then extend it with your own functions:

```
var key = $(this).data('key');
var obj = $(this).data(key);
obj.test = function() { console.log('Working!'); };
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/b2os4s7e/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just define:

```
$fn.unslider2 = function() { ... }
```

With any name and behaviour you like.

Comment: Don't get it. You say I should copy the content of unslider and create an own plugin called unslider2 with additional behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

For extend JQuery should use `.fn.extend`

```
(function($){ 
    $.fn.extend({
        helloworld: function(message){
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(){
                    alert(message);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

the object `.fn.extend` is used for extend funcionality of jQuery

Comment: Hey, I believe too that this is the desired way but I can't figure out how to apply it to unslider. The plugin expose it's functions to outside by setting an instance to the data element of the slider. However, If I use $.fn.extend, the functions in the core script is not accessible. what do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! I did it this way:

```
(function($){
    var originalMethod = $.fn.unslider;

    $.fn.extend({
        unslider: function(o) {
            var len = this.length;

            var applyMethod = originalMethod.apply( this, arguments );

            var key = applyMethod.data('key');
            var instance = applyMethod.data(key);

            //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it
            var me = $(this);

            if (instance) {
                instance.movenext = function (callback) {
                    return instance.stop().to(instance.i + 1, callback);
                };
                instance.moveprev = function (callback) {
                    return instance.stop().to(instance.i - 1, callback);
                };
            }

            return applyMethod.data(key, instance);

        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

The key was to address the data attribute as sroes suggested.

Moreover i needed to apply the original method, since i need the old methods.